# how to use replace() method if i am using android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Tags: java, android

Is there any way so I can use replace() method in 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' fragment?

Comment: SO does not allow such questions. You need to do something by yourselves. Ready for downvotes. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead `getFragmentManager()`

For example

`Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(fragment, "Fragment_tag").commit();`